# Кастомный infoWindow как добавить тень и переместить под маркер?

Tags: android, google-maps, infowindow

Здравствуйте господа!
есть такой код

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_dialog_address"
        style="@style/SecondaryTextView"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:text="text"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Выглядит это так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне же нужно что б infoWindow был под маркером
вроде этого:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

+ никак не могу адекватно добавить тень под infoWindow
Бьюсь уже третьи сутки, помогите пожалуйста кто чем может)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем нашёл решение,
в OnMarkerClickListener добавил строку установки позиции для InfoWindow.

```
marker.setInfoWindowAnchor(0.5f, 5f);
```

Где 0.5f это центр Вашего маркера, а 5f это то как низко будет InfoWindow.